# Best way to pass the value in Some to a function with a default parameter value?

Tags: scala

I have a function from a third party library as below :

```
def myfunction(input:String = "some constant value")
```

I have a

```
myinput:Option[String]
```

with me and I need to pass the function. Right now I am doing this:

```
myfunction(myinput.getOrElse("some constant value"))
```

But I dont want to look into the third party library for its default value.
What is the ideal way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
myinput.map(v => myfunction(v)).getOrElse(myfunction())
```

or more concise (as suggested by Pablo in the comments):

```
myinput.map(myfunction).getOrElse(myfunction())
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer. It could be more concise since  `myfunction` receives just one `String` parameter: `myinput.map(myfunction).getOrElse(myfunction())`

Comment: Agreed. Or to confuse future reviewers, `myinput map myfunction _ getOrElse myfunction()`

Comment: Even more concise if you use `fold` (more idiomatic too)

Comment: @Dima I agree that fold is the more idiomatic, however, I found that most people find it more confusing (especially those new to scala).

Comment: @AssafMendelson yeah ... if you are new to something, then the more idiomatic it is, the more confusing you find it :) "Most people", that are new to scala also find while loops and vars less "confusing" then `foreach` and `foldLeft` ... That's hardly the reason to stick with the former ... "Most people" can be educated.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this but my favorite one is using pattern matching. This code is also much readable.

```
myinput match {
     case Some(str) => myfunction(str)
     case _ => myfunction()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the best way, but you can do something like this:

```
if (myinput.isDefined){
  myfunction(myinput.get)
}
else{
  myfunction()
}
```

So if your `myinput` contains a value, use it, otherwise use the default-value.

Clearly, if you do this very often, you should outsource it to a function to just have one line at each call.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be a fold.
Assuming myfunction returns String we get:

```
val callIt: Option[String] => String = it => it.fold(myfunction())(myfunction(_))

callIt(None)
callIt(Some("abc"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is usually done with `.fold`:

```
myInput.fold(myfunction())(myfunction _)
```